# deleting from a list in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, list, selecteditem

I have a wpf c# application, that loads tasks to a treeView from a text file, the data about the tasks are loading into a list, Im trying to delete data in position I in the list, but i can not figure out how. I have this for loop checking to see if the selected treeView item is equal to the item in position I in the list and if so I wanna delete that item from the list. Here is the for loop which works, im just wondering how to do the actual delete, I've tried things such as `.delete` and `.remove` which I found on msdna.

```
for (int i = 0; i < name.Count; ++i)
{
       string selectName = ((TreeViewItem)(treeView1.SelectedItem)).Header.ToString();

       if (selectName == name[i])
       {

       //name.Remove(i) or name.Remove[i] or name[i].Remove
       }
}
```

Comment: Be careful about deleting objects in something you are looping through. You will have to adjust the index to compensate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If name is a `List<T>` then you probably want `name.RemoveAt(i)` if I understand the question correctly.

Alternatively, you could just use `name.RemoveAll(n => n == selectName);` instead of the for loop.

Comment: As someone else pointed out, if you do use the loop, you'll need to be careful with the indexes. I would recommend looping backwards:
`for(int i = name.Count-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)`

Comment: @Sunny I will, im still just working through the other parts of my delete task before i can see if it works correctly

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
string selectName = ((TreeViewItem)(treeView1.SelectedItem)).Header.ToString();
name.RemoveAll(x => x == selectedName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give [List.Remove()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx) an object, not an index.

So, assuming name is a List,

```
name.Remove((TreeViewItem)treeView1.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: You can also remove by index.

Comment: Be careful to delete objects from lists in general; double check that the equalitycomparer actually supports your use case. Otherwise, you might end up with a classic bug that silently always removes at Index #0 (because the equality comparer always matches)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your application needs, your data structure should have some time of Parent-Child relationship. All you should have to do is remove the `Child` that is selected from the parent, and the `TreeView` in `WPF` should just automatically update.

I suggest you read [Josh Smith's article on using `ViewModels` with the `TreeView`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx) for easier management. Trust me it will make your life a lot easier the sooner you start using a stronger data structure, and just remember that a `TreeView` only represents the data provided, and you should have other methods to edit the data directly and not the `TreeView`.